# jQeuer / AJAX - load whole external file into the 'ul' element

Tags: jquery

I working on the project now which will have massive multilevel menu - to make in easier to update in the future (site will be static html) I decide to stack menu in the separate file.

My question is:

- how to load whole content from external file in the `ul` element using jQuery?

E.g
HTML will be:

```
<ul class="menu">


</ul>
```

External file menu.html will look like:

```
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".menu").load("menu.html");
```

take a look to [jQuery's `.load()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: Deleted my answer, this one is far better. +1